# Can getline() or getdelim() return 0?

Tags: c

All descriptions of getline() and getdelim() say that they return the number of characters read, or -1 at end of file or error. Can they read no characters while not at end of file? Can I assume the return value will be nonzero?

Comment: You can't get 0 back from these functions.  You either get `-1` (indicating an EOF or an error) or at least `1` — there is no circumstance under which 0 is a valid.  The delimiter (e.g. newline, `'\n'`) is included in the output if present, so that's at least one character.  If you're at the end of the file, either the last character is a delimiter (in which case, the information is returned with a non-zero length, and the next read will return -1), or it is not a delimiter (in which case it is included in the output, so the output is not of length zero).  Memory allocation problems yield -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `getline()` and `getdelim()` cannot return 0.

Normally, `getline()` will read characters including the trailing `'\n'` that marks the end of a line, so it will always read at least one character.

The only exception to this is that the last line of input might not have a trailing `'\n'` character.

If the last line is not empty, `getline()` will read the characters making up the line and return a non-zero count.

It's not possible for the last line to be empty *and* have no trailing `'\n'` character. That's just an end-of-file condition, which causes `getline()` to return -1.

The same applies to `getdelim()`, with the delimiter character replacing the `'\n'` character.

Comment: And note that the functions [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) and 
[`getdelim()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) explicitly return `-1` and not `EOF`.  Even though `EOF` is usually `-1`, the [C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1) only requires it to be negative.

Comment: This is the confirmation I hoped for. I want to bail from the read loop if return is negative, then do `if (buf[k-1] == delim) buf[k-1] = '\0';` without having to check for `k==0`.